# Consistent auto-mount of external hard-drive

Tags: mount, fstab, automounting

Adding `/dev/sdb1 /home/[user]/external_drive ntfs defaults,noatime 0 2` to `/etc/fstab` auto-mounts external drive after machine start/reboot.

However, if additional usb drive was plugged in during the reboot, sometimes it is `/dev/sdb1` and it becomes accessible at `/home/[user]/external_drive` after the reboot.

Is there a way to consistently auto-mount each device so that each  device will be accessible via expected folder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `/dev/sdb1` which is not a unique identifier (`sdb1` will always be assigned to the first partition on second disk you plug in and during boot the order will be random with multiple plugged in external drives), use UUID instead (UUID is unique for every filesystem, so only the "right" device will be mounted to your `/home/[user]/external_drive`). You can find UUID of your device from `lsblk -f` output and then you can put `UUID=<uuid>` to your `fstab` instead of `/dev/sdb1`.

From `lsblk -f` you'll get something like this

```
$ lsblk -f /dev/sdb1
NAME FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sdb1 ntfs               0274801A52799A9F
```

so your `/etc/fstab` entry will look like

```
UUID=0274801A52799A9F /home/[user]/external_drive ntfs defaults,noatime 0 2
```

Note that with this entry, device with this specific UUID must be present during boot, I'd suggest adding `nofail` option to skip the entry (boot won't stop with an error) if the device is not present:

```
UUID=0274801A52799A9F /home/[user]/external_drive ntfs defaults,noatime,nofail 0 2
```

Comment: great answer, thanks. it worked

Comment: You may also want nofail and/or noauto parameters. If drive not plugged in boot will be slow as it has to timeout. And newer systemd autofs as x-systemd.automount. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/fstab#Automount_with_systemd example in link:  nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=1ms